# ¿Por qué me sale error cuando trato de importar en SASS?

Tags: sass, importación

estoy teniendo un problema con SASS. Estoy tratando de importar componentes a mi archivo principal (ejercicio-sass.scss) pero me da error. Ya revise los nombres de los archivos y están correctos.
Estoy usando Live Sass compiler para compilar el código sass.

[image: Acá se puede ver el error que me aparece.]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón es que tienes mal la estructura de ficheros, el archivo ejecicio-sass.scss está dentro de la carpeta de archivos compilados (css).
Deberías tener una estructura similar a esta:

- scss

  - componentes

    - (archivos .scss de los componentes)
  - ejercicio-sass.scss
- css

  - ejercicio-sass.min.css

Con esta estructura los imports estarían bien como los tienes.

Por otro lado, si deseas mantener la estructura que tienes ahora mismo (a mi parecer incorrecta), pues deberás cambiar los import:

```
@import '../componentes/globales';
```

Fíjate que no es necesario añadir la extensión en los import.

Comment: Muchas gracias!